# Long PHP Script keeps getting server error

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

Hi I am having an issue with a script in PHP,

It's basically only ever running at most 2 millions mysql queries so it takes a while to complete but before it can complete, the page keeps showing internal server error.

I have already included:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

so this leads me to beleive it's not the PHP causing it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your server logs for the actual error. It will help.

Comment: I am sure you can find more info problem in server or php error log. It could be out_of_memory limit as well. Some shared-hosting providers does not let you  change max_execution time so your ini_set in php code could be useless .

Comment: Change it in your php.ini directly

Comment: Internal Server Error is usually a fatal error. Find in your php.ini where errors are being saved. And it would help if you put the lines of code where it fails/crashes.

Comment: You're doing 2 million requests in a single script?  And you want to tie up a HTTP session for the duration of all those queries?  Not liking that design much, sorry.  At the very least you should be running the PHP script that does all that from a commandline instead, and not bring the HTTP server into it.

Comment: Could it be an HTTP request timeout error? http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408.html

Comment: @GordonM It has to be done through the server, it's the dashboard for a clients website for a gaming platform, It's not pretty but all that can be done for the client at this stage... Your answer doesn't really help solve my problem btw.

Comment: @AndréFigueira That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by just creating a seperate table with the instructions on what to add so it gets added by an hourly cron job.